# Does $f{(x)} = a x^4 - x^3 + ax - a$ have exactly $1$ positive root given $a>0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

Let $$f{(x)} = a x^4 - x^3 + ax - a$$ where $a>0$.
We know that it contains $4$ roots. Also, by the [Descartes' rule of signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes%27_rule_of_signs), we know that

1. There are either $1$ or $3$ positive roots.
2. There is exactly $1$ negative root.

I observed from plotting the function that it may contain exactly one positive root.

Therefore, can we prove/disprove that the function always contain a pair of conjugate complex roots?

Equivalently, can we prove/disprove that it has exactly $1$ positive root?

Comment: Compare with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/575504/prove-using-rolles-theorem-that-an-equation-has-exactly-one-real-solution), or [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1571492/if-the-real-polynomial-x4ax3bx2cxd-satisfies-d-0-and-3-a2-8-b) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f(x)=0$.

Thus, $$a=\frac{x^3}{x^4+x-1}.$$
Now, by the  Descartes' rule of signs we see that $x^4+x-1$ has an unique positive root $x_0$.

Thus, for $x>x_0$ we have $\frac{x^3}{x^4+x-1}>0$ and for $0<x<x_0$ we have $\frac{x^3}{x^4+x-1}<0$.

Now, $$\left(\frac{x^3}{x^4+x-1}\right)'=-\frac{x^2(x^4-2x+3)}{(x^4+x-1)^2}<0$$ for any $x>x_0$,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0^+}\frac{x^3}{x^4+x-1}=+\infty,$$ 
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{x^3}{x^4+x-1}=0,$$ and $\frac{x^3}{x^4+x-1}$ is a continuous on $(x_0,+\infty),$ which says that the equation 
$$a=\frac{x^3}{x^4+x-1}$$ or $$f(x)=0$$ has an unique positive root.

By the same way we see that the equation $f(x)=0$ has an unique negative root.